# Doubt related to ethers.getContractAt()

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

As we know `ethers.getContractAt()` is used in `ethers.getContractAt("contract_name",address)` way so the address to be passed in it must be the address where the contract was deployed?? like if we do `const sample = await deploy("Sample",{....` so the sample.address will be passed as address or any address i can pass??

Comment: This question is fairly unclear.  Please consider this guide on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can't pass any address, the address must belong to an existing contract, otherwise it will return an error (for example if an EOA address is used)

Answer (score 0):

`getContractAt()` comes from `hardhat-ethers`.

See interface in docs:
https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers.html#helpers

In order to use `getContractAt()`, you must pass in the address of the deployed contract, not just any address.

Example with `getContractAt()`:

```
const contractAddress = await ethers.getContractAt('YourContract', '0x...');
```

Contract instance:

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);
```